# retain query string between actions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, query-string

My controller has three actions:
Inroduction, Index and category.
In my master page I have a text box and a search button.
The general idea is that the user reaches the Introduction view, then types text into the textbox and clicks the search button.
He then sees the Index view, while the query string holds a value by which the data the user sees is filtered. the user can choose a category and then he is redirected to the category view.
How can I maintain the query string field and value (let's say "?cities=1,2,3") when I move between the actions Introduction, Index and category ?
I'll just point out that the query string value will change if the user enters new text in the textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to persist the initial qs values in a hidden form field. This will work as long as the user navigates from action to action using form submits. Another method which would not require form submits would be to persist to a cookie.

Comment: How can I append the hidden field to the form. I understand it can be acheived with a html helper, but how can I use the helper which renders the hidden field ? where do I call it ?

Comment: In your controller action you can put the value in your model then in your view, add the hidden field html helper inserting the value from your model into the value argument.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean that the user clicks a link (as opposed to a server-side redirect), your best bet is to convert the querystring values to hidden fields.

[See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219223/asp-net-mvc-getting-html-beginform-to-remember-querystring-params-when-submit).

Comment: thanks, but can you post some example code how to use the actual hidden field in addition to the html helper ? It would help me a lot ...