# MVC 5 AJax.Beginform Routevalues are generated wrongly

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, routes, ajax.beginform

I am trying to post to action the current querystring. So i have created the below extension method :

```
public static RouteValueDictionary ToRouteValues(this NameValueCollection col, Object obj = null)
        {
            var values = obj != null ? new RouteValueDictionary(obj) : new RouteValueDictionary();
            if (col == null) return values;
            foreach (string key in col)
            {
                //values passed in object are already in collection
                if (!values.ContainsKey(key)) values[key] = col[key];
            }
            return values;
        }
```

And in my view i am using the routvalues as below:

```
 using (Ajax.BeginForm(actionName: "Post", routeValues:Request.QueryString.ToRouteValues(), controllerName: "Request", ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "SuccessCallBack", UpdateTargetId = "successDiv", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter }, htmlAttributes: new { @data_toggle = "validator" }))
        {
        }
```

But strangely when the html markup is generated the form tag action does not have the actual querystring values but instead has a string version of the object metadata.

```
<form action="/Request/Post?Count=5&amp;Keys=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BKeyCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D&amp;Values=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BValueCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="Post" data-ajax-mode="after" data-ajax-success="SuccessCallBack" data-ajax-update="#successDiv" data-toggle="validator" id="form0" method="post" novalidate="true">
```

Comment: I think that in `Ajax.BeginForm` the controller name should come after action name and then, the third param can be the route values.

Comment: I tried that way also action,controller,routevalues etc still same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    actionName: "AddOns",
    controllerName: "Basket",
    routeValues: Request.QueryString.ToRouteValues(),
    ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "SuccessCallBack", UpdateTargetId = "successDiv", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter },
    htmlAttributes: new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "mainForm" } }))
{
    @:Blah
}
```

It outputs:

```
<form action="/Basket/AddOns?test=test" class="mainForm" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="Post" data-ajax-mode="after" data-ajax-success="SuccessCallBack" data-ajax-update="#successDiv" id="form0" method="post">
    Blah
</form>
```

Please note the last parameter which is a `Dictionary<string, object>`.

Used this post as source: [MVC3 Html.BeginForm - passing arguments as RouteValueDictionary fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028288/mvc3-html-beginform-passing-arguments-as-routevaluedictionary-fails#9030134)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your using named parameters and there are overloads of [Ajax.BeginForm()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.AjaxHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary,System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions%29) that accept both `object routeValues` and `RouteValueDictionary routeValues`.

In your case its using `object routeValues` and your generating a route value for each property of `RouteValueDictionary` (`Count`, `Keys`, etc). I'm assuming that's because the overload with `object routeValues` is defined first (but have yet to find anything documenting the behavior)

You can solve this by omitting the names and using

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Post", "Request", Request.QueryString.ToRouteValues(), new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "SuccessCallBack", UpdateTargetId = "successDiv", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter }, new { @data_toggle = "validator" }))
{
}
```

Comment: tried this by removing named parameters ,but still same issue

Comment: Works for me :)

Comment: Could it be anything outside of this code. Like i remember this used to work for me before. All of sudden it stopped working.

Comment: Can't think of anything. I'll test it a bit more later to see what might be causing it to use the overload with `object` rather than `RouteValueDictionary`.Which version of .NET and MVC? In the meantime you might try explicitly casting it (using `Request.QueryString.ToRouteValues() as RouteValueDictionary`)

Comment: the issue was with that last htmlAttributes. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh damn - I was lazy and just left off that attribute when I did my test. Your right when I tested it again with that parameter added it did generate it as `object` rather than `RouteValueDictionary` :)